# Can't resolve Snackbar with API24?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-snackbar

Im trying to implement the new Snackbars in my app but I can't
Why I can't use (Snackbar)?
I want to create the RuntimePermission for my application.
Here is my V24 details 
adroid version 2.3.1
Thanks

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.usr.alunonota10"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 3
            versionName "3.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
        compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

    }
```

Here is where I call the Snackbar

```
     if(permissionCheck!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(showRequestPermissions){
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), StringId, Snackbar.LENGHT_INDEFINITE).setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener()){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);

                }

            }).show();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
        }
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what you mean by "Why I can't use (Snackbar, Snackbar.make)?"

Comment: Im trying to implement the new Snackbars in my app but I can't @CommonsWare

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "I can't" means. What have you tried? What **specific** problems have you encountered?

Comment: Which device you use and what is android version?

Comment: when I post Snackbar in the code, it says "cannot resolve symbol Snackbar", i tryed to put the compile (snackbar:2.6.1) in my gradle but is not working @CommonsWare

Comment: API 24 and adroid version 2.3.1 @JavadKhan

Comment: I mean your device, Lollipop, Marshmallow or Nougat ?

Comment: nispok snackbar is deprecated. Please delete it. In appcompat package this already have.

Comment: @CommonsWare Really sorry, you're right, it was just import the Snackbar class -.-, thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

There is not any problem in your gradle scripts. Please make sure that, you call snackbar correctly! Check this code:

```
Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener).show();
```

Don’t forget to show!